# Lua string matching : how to find a target path

Tags: lua

Say I have a bunch of files that all follow the same pattern:

```
/tmp/project1/server_config.json
/tmp/project1/client_config.json
/tmp/project1/monitor_config.json
```

what I need is to extract the names:

```
server
client
monitor
```

If all I got is the full paths as a strings, is there a Lua method to extract the part that lies between `/tmp/projectXX/` and `_config.json` ?

Comment: Try `path:match(".*/(.+)_config.json")`.

Comment: @lhf well I feel dumb now, I focused so much on the folder indicated in the question that I completely flew over the much simpler `.*/` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `string.match` on your names and specify the correct regex like so:

```
local file_path = "/tmp/project1/client_config.json"
local filename_no_config = string.match(file_path, "/tmp/project[1-9]*/(.+)_config.json")

print(filename_no_config)
```

In this case `print` will write `client` and will work for `project` followed by whatever number (even bigger than 2 digits)

Comment: Pattern will work for the example paths, but note that `.+` may include `/`, which is probably not desirable here. Side note: Lua patterns are not to be confused with regex (they have features "true" regex doesn't have, and they lack choice (`|`), which regex has).

Comment: Is it the "+" symbol (or rather the `(.+)` ) that gets me the "thing I want" out of the pattern?

Comment: @LorahAttkins the `(.+)` means that it will match everything that is at least length 1. That means that will match E.G. `/tmp/project1/client_config.json` but not `/tmp/project1/_config.json`

Comment: @Luatic true, this will also match `/tmp/project1/foo/client_config.json` returning `foo/client`. I am honestly too rusty in Lua to remember the differences between patterns and regex so there may well be a better way to do this with some specific Lua thing that I'm not aware of/don't remember

Answer (score 4):

You need to be careful with the pattern. Assuming you want to match *exactly* the test strings you have given, where the filename may vary in the prefix, but the suffix needs to be `_config.json`, and the name of the `project` folder may vary in the suffix, use the pattern `^/tmp/project[^/]+/([^/]+)_config.json` for `string.match`:

```
print(("/tmp/project[^/]+/server_config.json"):match"^/tmp/project1/([^/]+)_config.json") -- server
```

Note also the nuances in the patterns by the other answerers:

- `/tmp/project%d+/(.-)_config.json` misses *anchors* (`^` and `$`). (Assuming this is unintended) this is a frequent mistake in Lua patterns. This will match anything that has something matching `/tmp/project%d+/(.-)_config.json` anywhere in it; it will also accept the `*_config.json` file being included in a subdirectory of the project. The following will match, for example: `/foo/bar/tmp/project42/subfolder/server_config.json.blah.blub`, and the match would be `subfolder/server`.
- `.*/(.+)_config.json` effectively matches just the filename, and removes a suffix of `_config.json`. Note that this also isn't anchored. A `^` anchor isn't needed here, as `.*` being greedy already suffices to start at the start of the string, but this pattern will allow arbitrary suffixes after `_config.json`. It will also allow arbitrary parent folders as it matches just the filename. `/blah/blub/server_config.json.blah.blub` would match as just `server`.
- `/tmp/project[1-9]*/(.+)_config.json` is similar to the first pattern in that it isn't anchored. It will pretty much have the same issues; it allows `[1-9]*` rather than `%d+` as the project folder suffix though.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to use string.match and %d+ to do this?
Say for example:

```
function extract_name(file_path)
    local pattern = "/tmp/project%d+/(.-)_config.json"
    local name = string.match(file_path, pattern)
    return name
end
```

%d represents a digit (0-9) and the '+' makes this match all combinations containing digits 0-9. This means that you can have more than the 3 directories you mentioned.

You could then create variables with the directories in and call on the function created above.

Hopefully that helped.